# Ksoap2 on android 3.2

Tags: ksoap2, android-3.2-honeycomb

I got a problem that ı developed an app (connecting an aspx web service) on Android 2.3 and it has been processing.

But I tried to same app on Android 3.2 I got some problems .

Is there any way for using Ksoap2 on Android 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug on 3.2 . try on 3.1 .that worked for me

Comment: I buy an tablet which has android 3.2 . Since that I have to do it on Android 3.2. İf ı write the codes can you help me about the error dila.